# RStudio Shiny Conditional Plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, shiny

Im trying to create a web application with the new RStudio feature Shiny, which plots different stocks. I created the following example.

I want to select the dataset StockMarket then select eg the DAX and then finally the plot should appear.

Right now if you run this code the plot appears immediately

Could you help me please?

```
ui.R:
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

# Application title
headerPanel("Plot1"),
sidebarPanel(
selectInput("dataset", "Dataset", list("mtcars"="cars", "StockMarket"="stocks")),

conditionalPanel(
  condition = "input.dataset=='stocks'",
  uiOutput("data")
)),
mainPanel(
plotOutput('plotstock')) ))


server.R:
library(shiny)
require(ggplot2)
library(datasets)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$data<- reactiveUI(function() {

selectInput("data", "Choose Dataset", colnames(EuStockMarkets))
})

output$plotstock <- reactivePlot(function() {
data<-data.frame(EuStockMarkets)
p<- ggplot(data,aes(x=seq(1,length(data[,1])),y=DAX))+geom_line(size=1)+ylab("")+opts(title="Time Series")
print(p)
 })})
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the `reactivePlot` function you can do something like

```
if (is.null(input$data))
  return(NULL)
```

I would also add a blank entry to the dataset choices (`"(Choose one)"=""`) and also have

```
if (!nzchar(input$dataset))
  return(NULL)
```

in `reactivePlot`.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that you check for empty strings

```
if (!nzchar(input$dataset) || input$dataset=='')
return(NULL)
```